# How to achive this Scenario: PayPal Recurring + Trial period + Base Price

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

I'm trying to achieve the following scenario using PayyPal:

We have a subscription with a trial period with  price  X. The subscription Purchase (Base) price is Y and the recurring price is Z. When the subscriber makes a purchase he should be billed with the trial price ( X). After the trial ends the subscriber will get billed  with the purchase price ( Y).  Then when the subscription period ends the recurring should happen and bill the customer with the recurring price (Z).

Example: 
 1. You Checkout
 2. You get Billed with X USD ( Trial price )
 3. You Get billed with Y USD ( Base Price ) one time only.
 4. You Get billed with Z USD ( Recurring Price )

Is this scenario possible? What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Add some sample code you are working with. What apis are you using. How do you plan to accomplish the task. What database are you using to store the data. How do you make your calls? This site helps people solve coding solutions, you will get more answers when presenting simplified coding problems rather than logic problems.

Comment: It sounds like you need to find a developer. SO isn't intended for this kind of storyboarding.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be creating a subscription button out of your PayPal account and then posting that HTML code to your site. You can set trial periods in the subscription button.